# Span Click Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why is the click event not fired here

**HTML**

```
<div class="checkboxBtn">
  <span class="cheked" onclick="CheckSelected();"></span>
  <input id="23" type="checkbox"></input>
  <label>Compare Now </label>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function CheckSelected() {
        alert("");
    }
```

[image]

The checkbox in the image is the span tag

Comment: The div is a slighlty larger unit covering the checkbox. That would fire if user clicks anywhere outside the checkbox too right

Comment: unless you have css making the span cover the label and input (which I doubt if you are able to click it), the span has no width or height so you won't be able to click it.  Why not put the input inside the label and then styling that [see this for css3 styled checkboxes](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953) or add the checkselected function to the parent div

Answer (score 4):

In your html, there is nothing enclosed within the span tag, so nothing can be clicked. Try enclosing the input and label tags within the span tag and you should be able to fire your CheckSelected() function.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is nothing in your `<span>`, so it is 0px by 0px, hence there is nothing (visible) to click.

Also, `<input>` elements are self-closing, you don't include `</input>`.

Maybe you meant to wrap your `<span>` around your `<input>`:

```
<div class="checkboxBtn">
    <span class="cheked" onclick="CheckSelected();">
        <input id="23" type="checkbox">
    </span>
    <label>Compare Now </label>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jfu9hds5/4/)

Or, your `<span>` around your `<input>`:

```
<div class="checkboxBtn">
    <input id="23" type="checkbox">
    <span class="cheked" onclick="CheckSelected();">
        <label>Compare Now </label>
    </span>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jfu9hds5/5/)

Comment: @Qwerty Glad to have helped.

Comment: Does he input have a closing tag </input> ?

Comment: @Billy Pete's point prompted me to notice that too. I've addressed the issue.

Comment: Its turns out that <span class="uncheked"> is dynamically generated. So when I enclosed the current input inside teh span, a new uncheked span tag came in which is the actual checkbox now. I Just want to fire a click event when user clicks on the checkbox. Not working with current code :(

Comment: @Qwerty why not add an onchange event to the checkbox instead of an onclick to the image of the checkbox: `<input id="23" onchange="CheckSelected();" type="checkbox">`

Comment: The second fiddle is not firing the alert. Same as in my case.

Comment: @Pete.Tried the onchange.Still alert does not pop